# Accessing command line arguments to npm script

Tags: npm-scripts

This is what i have in my package.json file, in the scripts section:

```js
{
  "version": "0.0.1",
},
"scripts": {
  "dev-wip": "environment=DEV --tags=@wip"
}
```

This is how my command line:

```
npm run dev-wip
```

I have no problem accessing variables in the package.json file, by doing this:

```js
var pjson = require('../../../package.json');
console.log('version - ' + pjson.version);
```

I want to be able to access the environment parameter (print the value, for example) that i got from the command line.

Comment: Are you asking how to access environment variables in your project or in your package.json file?

Comment: Yes, i guess. As this value is not something  that is being passed from the command line. The issue is the "environment" in my example is not configured anywhere.

Comment: Answering yes to an open question does not help me understand what you want to achieve. Please update your question accordingly.

Comment: I just discovered how to do and answered my own question. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
Using this will give my the value of the "environment" parameter (which is "DEV" in my example).

```
process.env.environment
```